# How to make vite recognize Netlify env vars

Tags: environment-variables, netlify, vite

I'm using a file named `.env.local` in dev environment, and all env vars work fine!

When I pushed it to Netlify, they aren't located, is there some specific way of setting them?

I also seted them in Netlify.

[image]

But, I keep getting this error log:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In my case, I had to trigger a new deploy, so that the environment variables you set in Netlify get injected into the code.

Go to *Deploys > Trigger deploy*.

[image]